# ruby circular references example

Tags: ruby, memory, garbage-collection, circular-reference

I read some article about ruby garbage collector and many mentioned about circular reference object can not be cleared. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003808/does-this-code-create-a-circular-memory-reference-in-ruby) mentioned about circular reference but I'm not sure whether it will cause the problem. Any one could give some examples of how to create a circular references?

Comment: As the answer to the question you linked already points out, Ruby's GC can very much collect objects with circular references. I don't know where you read that it can't, but that's misinformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read some article about ruby garbage collector and many mentioned about circular reference object can not be cleared.

That's absolutely not true.

> Any one could give some examples of how to create a circular references?

Most trivially like this:

```
arr1 = []
arr2 = [ arr1 ]
arr1 << arr2
```

However, as I said (and as the answer to the question you linked also points out), Ruby's GC will have absolutely no problem collecting `arr1` and `arr2` after they go out of scope.